# Display number output field as whole number

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom field who's type is *number*, with format: 18 digit, 0 decimal places. However, when I output it using `<apex:outputfield value="soBject__c.Number__c" />` for example, it displays: **18.0** dispite the fact that it's *0 decimal places* in the number?

Is there anyway to hide the **.0** ? Or do I just need to *convert it to a string*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found that by far the easiest/simplest way to achieve this is to just use the `FLOOR()` Visualforce function:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!FLOOR(sObject.Number__c)}"/>
```

Comment: This works great when the scale is 0 (your case).

Comment: Yeah, you don't want to use it for situations where you want to keep your decimal part (or round correctly), but when scale is 0 and you don't want the `.0` showing, it's the option with the cleanest markup IMO.

Comment: I agree that this is much simpler than the MessageFormat, and therefore better IMO. This question only asks specifically about whole numbers with 0 decimal places which this method covers.

Answer (score 8):

would formatting do the trick?

```
   <apex:outputText value="{0,number,#,##0}">$    
       <apex:param value="{!soBject__c.Number__c}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
```

Comment: That's what I do as well.  For reference, the outputText supports the syntax of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html.  You can look at the related Format classes (e.g., subclasses of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/Format.html such as DecimalFormat) for the various format Strings.