# Formatting number values on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I am wondering if it is possible to dynamically format input numbers in Visualforce components when rendering as HTML. I am able to successfully accomplish this when rendering as output tags doing the following:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}">
    <apex:param value="{!myNumber}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Which yields a value of 123,456 provided myNumber is an Integer of 123456. In an ideal world, this would work in inputText as well (and there are ways to accomplish this via javascript), but I am curious if there is anything "out of the box" with Salesforce.

**UPDATE:** Modified original question after noticing a syntax error.

Comment: See: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/display-number-output-field-as-whole-number 

The answers here helped me!

Comment: To clarify are you looking to validate an input against a given format, for instance a regular expression?

Comment: Not necessarily validation. The question itself is a bit skewed as my original question involved a syntax error that I caught rendering formatted outputText, but I was curious if there was a way to "format" numbers in an inputText. For example, if the fields value is 400000, we'd like the field to display as 400,000 and then save again as 400000. I am under the impression that only Javascript would be able to handle this, but was wondering if Salesforce had anything built in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any built-in SF function that will achieve exactly what you want. But you might be able to get close by mixing in a bit of javascript. The below is something I have scratched out here and isnt complete but should go the right way.

I think you could use a combination of a hidden inputText field to hold the value and an output field for displaying. When the outputText is clicked on it is hidden by a js function and the inputText is shown. When the input text is changed a js function hides the input and an actionSupport fires to update the outputText display. The action support may need to also update the controller with the new value but I havent added that at the moment.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Object.myNumber}" id="myNumberInput"onclick="hideInput('myNumber')">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="myNumberDisplay"/>
</apex:inputField> 

<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}" id="myNumberDisplay" onclick="showInput('myNumber')">
    <apex:param value="{!myNumber}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: I believe that you are correct, Javascript is probably the only way to handle this -- though I suspect we need to be aware of parsing out all the non numeric characters when saving, so it mind end up with some interesting implementations.