# How to format number with comma in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting one value from webservice as a string (KM value , say 500000) . I want to display that in an inline vf page as 50,000. How to achieve this in apex controller. I am displaying the valu in a apex datatable as column value.

Please help me out

Eg ; 50000 should be 50,0000 OR 5000000 should be 5,000,000

Comment: Have a look here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/formatting-number-values-on-visualforce-page

Answer (score 4):

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}" id="myNumberDisplay" >
    <apex:param value="{!myNumber}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Use apex:outputText with apex:param to format the text. as you are using datatable so it will look like

```
<apex:column>
   <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}" id="myNumberDisplay" >
        <apex:param value="{!myNumber}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:column>
```

In controller you can try this

```
Decimal rA = 1298763.86;
List<String> args = new String[]{'0','number','###,###,##0.00'};
String s = String.format(rA.format(), args);
System.debug(s);
```

but still first you need to break the string using `'-'`

Comment: I am getting values from controller as 0-50000. If i put these above syntax in vf page , i am getting the not a valida type error. May be anyone pls tell me how to concatenate two values in apex param

Comment: I am not sure about two values. In this case you need to handle them in controller.