# Put a comma in a number larger than 999 in visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, email

I have this visualforce tag

```
<td align="center">{!IF(relatedTo.Total_Professional_Services_Before_Disc__c=0, "--", "$" + TEXT(ROUND(relatedTo.Total_Professional_Services_Before_Disc__c,0)))}</td>
```

and the idea is that if it is 0, it will output '--' else the number in US currency format. It works fine but let's say the number is 9999, it will output

```
$9999
```

Is there a simple way to make it output

```
$9,999
```

without creating a controller as this is just in a simple visualforce email template?

Edit:
Thank you to those that answered. Final solution came out to be

```
<td align="center">
  <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,##0}" rendered="{!IF(relatedTo.Total_Professional_Services_Before_Disc__c=0, false, true)}">
    <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Total_Professional_Services_Before_Disc__c}"/>
  </apex:outputText>
  <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(relatedTo.Total_Professional_Services_Before_Disc__c=0, true, false)}">--</apex:outputText>
</td>
```

It isn't pretty and I can't say I'm excited to replace 28 tags in a table like this, but it works

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118624/how-to-format-number-with-comma-in-apex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use outputText to print a formatted number with ***rendered*** attribute to define whether to print the number or the double dash (--).

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}">
    <apex:param value="{!myNumber}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Using this method, how would you add the '$'

Comment: Just place value="${0, number, ###,##0}".

Answer (score 1):

with $ sign ...

```
<apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,##0}">
    <apex:param value="{!myNumber}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```